# Minimizing the application form causes a modal form to close, but not a MessageBox

Tags: c#, winforms

If I programatically minimize the application's form while a modal dialog is open, that modal dialog gets closed.

However, if I programatically minimize the application's form while a MessageBox is open, the MessageBox is not closed (i.e. when I restore the application to normal window state, the message box is still showing).

Here's my sample code demonstrating the difference:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        // ... 

        private void showMessageBoxBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Start();

            // This MessageBox does *not* get closed when the WindowState of Form1 is set to minimized in timer1_Tick
            MessageBox.Show(this, "MessageBox");
        }

        private void formShowDialogBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Start();

            // This form gets closed when the WindowState of Form1 is set to minimized in timer1_Tick
            Form2 form2 = new Form2();
            form2.ShowDialog(); 
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
            timer1.Stop();
        }
    }
```

**Question:**

Is there a way to get the Form to behave like the MessageBox?

Comment: I can't restore window state when form was minimized with opened message box. Are you sure you have this code in real application?

Comment: Yes. Brand new Winforms app with the above code. I can't minimize it (except for using code), but I can restore it by clicking on it in the taskbar.  That said, Alt-tab doesn't seem to show it.

Comment: Strange.. I can't restore form neither by clicking on taskbar, nor with alt-tab

Comment: Here's what I see: http://www.screencast.com/t/ktmpVDovma

Comment: Have you tried and see if the form2.ShowDialog() returns a DialogResult when the main form is minimized? Maybe it is by behavior of .Net

Comment: this is a rare approach, if you dont mind, why do you want to minimized the form in the `timer_tick event`?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky I'm getting the same behavior

Comment: @Żubrówka same as mine, or same as Matt has?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky As you, with the MessageBox I'm not able to restore

Comment: @spajce, This was just an easy way to show the problem.  The real application doesn't use the timer.

Comment: @Quintium, DialogResult is Cancel, and CloseReason is None.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your feedback, I'm very appreciative of everyone's time invested in looking into this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you are seeing is the side-effect of countermeasures built in to Winforms to deal with dialog usability problems, countermeasures that the MessageBox() function doesn't have.  They were probably more relevant to Windows 98, originally an important target operating system for Winforms, too long ago for me to remember accurately.

An important usability problem is what happens when you show a dialog and it gets minimized.  A dialog disables all other windows in the app so you can no longer activate them.  The dialog should have its ShowInTaskbar property set to false.  The user now has a problem, there is no simple way to get back to the dialog.  Nothing to click on.

Winforms avoids this trap by automatically closing the dialog.  As you can tell, MessageBox doesn't do this.  It can not reasonably do this either, it doesn't have a good way to return a "dialog was canceled" status code.

Notable is that this trap still partially exists.  On my Win8 machine, I can click the disabled form's taskbar button and get it to move back in the foreground.  But that activates the disabled form instead of the message box.  Major UI blooper there and nasty if the message box is behind that form.

So to answer your question: no.  Feature, not a bug.

Comment: Great answer (as always).  Thanks.  While doing some more testing on this, I was suprised to see that modal WPF forms don't have the same feature--they don't get closed upon application minimize.

Answer (score 1):

First, declare the `Form2` form variable outside the method's scope, so it could be reachable from the `timer1_tick` method. Then, when the `Timer` ticks, minimize the main form, but show the modal dialog and then minimize it.

Try this:

```
Form2 form2;

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
    form2.Show();
    form2.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
    timer1.Stop();
}
```

Comment: @MattSmith, your question was: _Is there a way to get the Form to behave like the MessageBox?_. This is what my answer does. It shows the dialog as modal once you click on the main form in the task bar. Sorry, but maybe I missed the question's point.

Comment: Sorry, misread your answer and dismissed it too quickly.  This is interesting. I don't really understand why it works (do you). For my real purposes, it won't quite work, because I wouldn't want Form2 to have to know when the main application is being minimized (i.e. the code that minimizes the application shouldn't have knowledge of form2).  That said, it certainly does seem to match the MessageBox behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Matt,

Try changing:

```
form2.ShowDialog();
```

to

```
form2.Show(this);
```

Is this the behavior you are looking for?

Comment: No.  I need a modal dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication37
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern IntPtr GetParent(IntPtr hWnd);

        Form2 form2 = null;
        IntPtr parent = IntPtr.Zero;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void formShowDialogBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Start();

            // This form gets closed when the WindowState of Form1 is set to minimized in timer1_Tick
            form2 = new Form2();
            form2.ShowDialog();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
            timer1.Stop();
        }

        private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
            {
                this.parent = GetParent(form2.Handle);
                SetParent(form2.Handle, IntPtr.Zero);
                form2.Hide();
            }
            else
            {
                SetParent(form2.Handle, this.parent);
                form2.ShowDialog();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that this is somewhat an hack, I'm not totally sure about consequences. Criticism is acceptable :)

Comment: Re-showing it would kind of work.  But, I wouldn't want to require my parent form to know about all its children form (or have them register). Also, dialog's would have to be aware that they could be used in this way: i.e. things like location of the dialog would need to be remembered since it isn't the same when its shown the 2nd time if the user had moved the dialog.  Thanks for the idea, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you set

```
Visible = true;
```

on the modal form immediately after programmatically minimizing the owner from, the modal form does not get killed by the OS.

So

```
ownerForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
```

will kill the modal form. But

```
ownerForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
modalForm.Visible = true;
```

will not kill it.